# Best way to check what a variable is

Tags: php

I was wondering what the quickest way would be to do something like the following:

```
if ($var == 1) {
// 1
}
if ($var == 2) {
// 2
}
if ($var == 3) {
// 3
}
```

etc, but then at the end having something like:

```
if ($var != 1 or 2 or 3) {
//Not a number
}
```

I was thinking about having an `if(in_array(...))` statement at the end, but wanted to know your thoughts.

Comment: how is `$var` used in those cases ? can it be used direcly ?

Answer (score 6):

I would do this with a `switch`

```
switch ($var) {
    case 0:
        echo "var equals 0";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "var equals 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "var equals 2";
        break;
    default:
       echo "var is not 0 1 or 2"
}
```

Also if you miss out a `break` statement then you can easily do a case when `$var == 1 || $var == 2`, [read more](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to know is whether "$var" is in your set {1, 2, 3}, then in_array is fine.

Otherwise, if you want to know *which* (if any) value you've got, then I'd do this:

```
if ($var == 1) {
// 1
}
else if ($var == 2) {
// 2
}
else if ($var == 3) {
// 3
}
else {
}
```

Note the "else if" to save you from re-checking what you already know.

Note, too, that PHP 4 and 5 also have a "switch" case/block:

```
switch ($i) {
    case 1:
         // 1
        break;
    case 2:
         // 2
        break;
    case 3:
         // 3
        break;
    default:
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use a switch case, this better to read for much cases:

```
switch($var) {
    case 1: /*1*/ break;
    case 2: /*2*/ break;
    case 3: /*3*/ break;
    default: /*not 1 not 2 not 3*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if/else if/else`, with which you can decide whether strict or loose comparisons are appropriate.

With `switch`, it's always *loose* comparisons, which is why I prefer the `if` statement, since it makes it explicit what mode has been chosen.

```
if ($var === 1) {
// 1
}
else if ($var === 2) {
// 2
}
else if ($var === 3) {
// 3
}
else {
//neither 1, 2 nor 3
}
```